In Dart's Uint32List.sublistView function, why should start argument be a multiple of 4?
I was writing a program to unpack Uint8 and Uint32 integers from a byte stream, and encountered this issue where I couldn't pass a non-multiple-of-4 value as start argument of Uint32List.sublistView() function. I understand that end - start should be a multiple of 4, but why should the value of start be multiple of 4?

Example:
Assume that I have a byte stream which represents an array of Uint32s. The first byte of the stream is a Uint8 value representing the count of Uint32 values. Below is a simplified version of the code I am trying to accomplish.
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
    // First byte (2) represents the number of Uint32 values. The 2 Uint32 values are 7 and 5
    // represented in Endian.little. Please note this is just a simplified representation, 
    // I do have other data elements in my original byte stream.
    var bytes = Uint8List.fromList([2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]);

    // I would just like pull the Uint32 values list without performing any copy.
    // as in the below line.
    var uint32List = Uint32List.sublistView(bytes, 1, 1 + bytes[0]*4);

    // However, the above line throws
    // RangeError: Offset (1) must be a multiple of BYTES_PER_ELEMENT (4) error.
    // Instead I have to copy the bytes to a different buffer
    // or use some kind of iteration over ByteData. like:
    var elements = Uint8List.fromList(Uint8List.sublistView(bytes, 1)); // copy bytes
    print(Uint32List.sublistView(elements)); // prints [7, 5]
}


Dart documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.4.4/dart-typed_data/Uint32List/Uint32List.sublistView.html

If your data is not size-aligned and may not be the same endianness as the platform, then you should probably use ByteData to read it. It has slightly more overhead than a direct Uint32List, but it can do unaligned reads on any platform (simulating it on platforms that do not allow that in the CPU) and it can reorder the bytes if reading a different endianness than the CPUs.
Using Uint32List is best for storing data that you've written yourself, in this process, or created and written by a prior run of the same program on the same computer. Then it can safely assume the endianness.

A Uint32List is expected to be aligned to a 32-bit boundary for performance.  To fix your problem, you can do one of:

Treat your byte stream as a Uint8List and build 32-bit integers yourself with shifts and masks (which is what would happen anyway if you were allowed to perform unaligned reads/writes).
Treat your byte stream as a Uint8List and copy it to another Uint32List.
If you control the byte stream, make the count a 32-bit value too or add padding bytes so that the rest of the payload is aligned to a 32-bit boundary.


Thank you. This is interesting. I would have to read about this. Maybe, I am using Uint32List wrong. It is not meant for the purpose that I am using it for. I would better use ByteData.sublistView() and call ByteData.getUint32() in a loop. It would avoid copying data.

@SunilB Sure, you could do that.  That would be equivalent to the first method I listed; ByteData.getUint32() would just be doing the shifts and masks for you.

More likely  getUint32(i, Endian.little) will just do an unaligned read on little-endian CPUs that support that. On CPUs that don't, it will do two aligned reads and some shifts and masks. On big-endian CPUs (if ever), there will be more byte-shuffling.
If you are running on an x64 CPU, you can probably safely assume that getUint32 is just a single unaligned memory read (and maybe some bounds checks)
